# Best way to do site level configuration

Tags: office-dev-pnp

I'm not sure if this will be a duplicate or not - I've had a search and can't find it.

My issue is, I have the need to add custom configuration/properties to sites when they are provisioned, so these are for example a Project Reference where the site is being used as a project, also a project level which indicates whether it is simple, standard or complex (and the latter can change mid-project).  A lot of other stuff on the site, on multiple pages, depends on what has been set in these properties, which suggests leaving them in PropertyBag and writing some JS to get them and display them.  The examples I've seen use OfficeDevPNP provisioning to set PropertyBag entries, and then map these to Page columns, but this means that the values are specific to the page and I need them to be at site level - other pages need access to the same values.  So I'm thinking maybe a list but can't find any way to populate a list from OfficeDevPNP.

Has anyone had a similar problem?  Any useable solutions or even just discussion points would be helpful!

Thanks